# Blum's speedup theorem showing unclassifiable complexity languages?

Tags: complexity-theory

Do any of [Blum's theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem) prove that there exist decidable languages that are unclassifiable anywhere in the [time hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy)? In other words, asserting they (mentioned in the proofs) are computable within any time $O(f(n))$ for some [time-constructable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constructible) function $f(n)$ leads to a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

If a language is decidable then it is accepted by some Turing machine. The running time of that Turing machine is by definition time-constructible. So any computable function has a time-constructible upper bound by definition.

Comment: If the Turing machine runs in log(N) time on the input, is that time-constructible? I thought log(N) was not time-constructible.

Comment: The running time of a Turing machine is always time-constructible. If $\log n$ is not time-constructible then it is not the running time of a Turing machine.

Comment: What about the complexity class DLOGTIME?

Comment: DLOGTIME is defined on random-access machines, for this very reason.

Comment: Does an analogue of the time hierarchy theorem exist for random-access machines - either for random-access Turing machines or register machines (RAMs)?

Comment: The same diagonalization proof should work.